# Using TRY...CATCH in Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, try-catch

I have the written the T-SQL code below. I want to put it in a SQL Server TRY...CATCH block. However, because I must execute some statements before proceeding with another statement, I am using the GO keyword and this makes the code crash with out executing the code in the CATCH block. It just crashes as if there was no CATCH block. If I remove the GOs in the code and the code crashes, the execution jumps to the CATCH block which is the desired behavior.

Any ideas on what I can do?

```
BEGIN TRY
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK = 'D:\Folder1\Database1.bak'
GO

ALTER DATABASE BusinessData
SET SINGLE_USER WITH
ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

ALTER DATABASE BusinessData 
SET RECOVERY Simple

RESTORE DATABASE BusinessData
FROM DISK = 'D:\Folder1\Database1.bak'
WITH MOVE 'BusinessData' TO 'C:\MyDATA

\BusinessData.mdf',
MOVE 'BusinessData_log' TO 'C:\MyDATA

\BusinessData_log.ldf'

ALTER DATABASE BusinessData SET MULTI_USER

GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'SERVER1\user1')
CREATE LOGIN [SERVER1\user1] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=

[us_english]
GO

USE [ProjectServer_Authentication]

GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'SERVER1\user1')
CREATE USER [SERVER1\user1] FOR LOGIN [SERVER1\user1] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner',N'SERVER1\user1'
GO

USE [BusinessData]
IF NOT  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'SERVER1\user1')
CREATE USER [SERVER1\user1] FOR LOGIN [SERVER1\user1] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner',N'SERVER1\user1'
GO

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
USE msdb
GO
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='My Mail Profile',
@recipients='myemailaccount@mydomain.org',
@subject='Refresh Error',
@body='Email body'
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think GO is the Problem as

> GO is not a Transact-SQL statement;
>
> it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.
> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should send the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL Server. **The current batch of statements is composed of all statements entered since the last GO**, or since the start of the ad hoc session or script if this is the first GO.

With every GO you start a new Statement, wich means your begin Try and your End Try are in 2 different Statements and therefore not working